# Filtering a Scala List by type

Tags: scala

I have a class structure like this

```
abstract class A
class B extends A
class C extends A
class D extends A
class E extends A
```

and I have a collection of the various instances, for example:

```
val xs = List(new D, new B, new E, new E, new C, new B)
```

My question is, is there an elegant way to filter out some of the subclasses from the List?

Let's say I want all instances except B's and C's. I can do it with a bunch of isInstanceOf's, or using collect like this:

```
val ys = (xs collect {
    case b: B => None
    case c: C => None
    case notBorC => notBorC
}).filter(_ != None).asInstanceOf[List[A]]
```

This works but it feels awkward, mostly because of the filter and cast. Is there a more elegant way? Less code is preferred, and I'd like to have a solution that doesn't need to be updated if I add more subclasses of A.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`flatMap` that shit! ([as they say](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8559537/334519)):

```
scala> val ys = xs flatMap {
     |   case _: B | _: C => None
     |   case other => Some(other)
     | }
ys: List[A] = List(D@7ecdc97b, E@2ce07e6b, E@468bb9d1)
```

In your case you were getting a `List[ScalaObject]` because `ScalaObject` is the least upper bound of `None`, `D`, and `E`.

Comment: Yes, this is a much better solution than my first attempt.

Comment: For those (like myself), wondering how this works: there's an implicit conversion `option2iterable` happening, converting the `Some`/`None` values to iterables. An alternative way to write this, not to incur the implicit conversion would be to use `collect` followed by `flatten` instead of `flatMap`. Great answer, Travis!

Comment: FYI I was using this approach originally, and my process took ~90 seconds to complete. I switched to using @Grozz approach and the runtime dropped to 8 seconds. I believe it's because it skips creating all the intermediate Option instances.

Answer (score 110):

`collect` can be used to filter values on which the function is defined:

Get all values of type A:

```
xs.collect { case a: A => a }
```

Get all values except B and C:

```
xs diff xs.collect { case x@(_: B | _: C) => x }
```

Answer (score 4):

Formulating problems as questions seems to be a pretty good way of solving them :) My question actually provides the answer - just filter by subtype:

```
val ys = xs filterNot(List(classOf[B], classOf[C]) contains _.getClass)
```

Comment: Should your intention be that ``ys`` is the empty list if your exclusion lists contains ``classOf[A]``, then you will need something differently. For example: ``xs.filterNot(x => List(classOf[A]).exists(y => y.isInstance(x)))``. Travis' solution exhibits this property as well.

Comment: @mhs: True, though in my case A is abstract so having it in the exclusion list is not relevant. Anyway, I agree that Travis' flatMap solution is superior also to this one.

Comment: No, I don't agree that travis solution is necessarily superior to your solution. Your's could be abstracted in the set of classes you would like to filter out, Travis' solution could not be abstracted in that direction. But you use a set instead of a list in the argument to filterNot.