# Scala flatMap filter elements in array instance of Type

Tags: scala, casting, apache-spark-ml

I am curious how to filter the elements of an array in scala by class.

```
case class FooBarGG(foo: Int, bar: String, baz: Option[String])
val df = Seq((1, "first", "A"), (1, "second", "A"),
    (2, "noValidFormat", "B"),
    (1, "lastAssumingSameDate", "C"))
  .toDF("foo", "bar", "baz")
  .as[FooBarGG]
  .drop("replace")

  val labelEncoder = multiLabelIndexer(columnsFactor)
  val pipe = new Pipeline().setStages(labelEncoder)
  val fitted = pipe.fit(df)

  def multiLabelIndexer(factorCols: Seq[String]): Array[StringIndexer] = {
    factorCols.map(
      cName => new StringIndexer()
      .setInputCol(cName)
      .setOutputCol(s"${cName}_index")
      )
    .toArray
  }
```

Could not get `flatMap` to work, as a `Transformer` and not `StringIndexerModel` is expected.

```
stages flatMap {
    //      case _.isInstanceOf[StringIndexerModel] => Some(_)//Some(_.asInstanceOf[StringIndexerModel])
    case StringIndexerModel => Some(_)
    case _ => None
  }
```

My approach is based on [Filtering a Scala List by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381797/filtering-a-scala-list-by-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use collect

`Collect` is much more clear and elegant

```
stages collect { case a: StringIndexerModel => a }
```

In case of `collect` you do not need to return `Some` and `None` values, instead Just choose the one you need and ignore the other cases this is the reason why the collect is more elegant.

Also `isInstanceOf` is redundant and verbose when using the pattern matching because pattern matching can be used to figure out outer types.

For example

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)

list match {
  case a: List => //no need to use isInstanceOf
  case _ =>
}
```

*Notice we can only figure out the type as List, but cannot figure out List[Int] because of type erasure*

Answer (score 0):

Using a named parameter and not matching any type is the solution.

```
case c: StringIndexerModel => Some(c)
case _ => None
```