# When and why does the collect method fail for filtering Scala Collections by subtype?

Tags: scala

Related to [Filtering a Scala List by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381797/filtering-a-scala-list-by-type), I'm trying to filter a Map by the type of the values but am finding that the solution with the `collect` method yields a type error.

For instance, consider

```
abstract class A
class B extends A
class C extends A

val collection: Map[String, A] = Map(("One", new B), ("Two", new B), 
  ("Three", new C), ("Four", new C))

val filtered: Map[String, B] = collection.collect { 
  case x@(_: String, _: B) => x }
```

This yields a compilation error saying that `Map[String, A]` is found when `Map[String, B]` is required. Isn't the point of the PartialFunction parameter for `collect` that it is only defined on some of the values?

However, this method works for Lists (as in the linked post):

```
val collection: List[A] = List(new B, new B, new C, new C)

val filtered: List[B] = collection.collect { case x: B => x }
```

But, upon further experimentation, I found it also doesn't work for Lists of Lists. This yields a runtime error that `C` can't be cast to `B`:

```
val collection: List[List[A]] = List(List(new B), List(new B), 
  List(new C), List(new C))

val filtered: List[List[B]] = collection.collect { case x: List[B] => x }
```

What's going on here? Are there multiple things going on that I'm missing?

---

As a sidenote, one of the solutions given does work:

```
val collection: Map[String, A] = Map(("One", new B), ("Two", new B), 
  ("Three", new C), ("Four", new C))

val filtered = collection.flatMap {
  case x@(_: String, _: B) => Some(x)
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: The `List[List[B]]` issue is a type-erasure one (so unrelated to the main question, which is about the type inference around `collect`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `x` is a variable of type `(String, A)`. `@` returns the element that successfully `unapply`, which is the original element of the map `(String, A)`.

A way to solve it is creating a new tuple with the values extracted from the pattern matching (because they are String and B by definition).

```
val collection: Map[String, A] = Map(("One", new B), ("Two", new B), ("Three", new C), ("Four", new C))

val filtered:Map[String, B] = collection.collect {
  case (k: String, v: B) => (k, v)
}

filtered.foreach(println)
```