# Spark Cassandra List Data type Mapping

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I started testing Spark with Cassandra. 
I get data from Cassandra which has two columns (primary key, set).

```
val sc = new SparkContext("spark://172.31.32.224:7077","test", conf)
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "table").select("pk", "lists")
.map(l => (l.get[String]("pk"), l.getList[String]("lists")))
```

But this code is mapping `(String, Seq[String])`
I'd like to break the `Seq[String]` and make pairs with "pk", such as

```
((pk1, list(1)), (pk1, list(2), (pk1, list(3)))
```

Is there way to do this?

Comment: FlatMap that ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559537/where-does-the-flatmap-that-s-idiomatic-expression-in-scala-come-from  :-)

Comment: Any reason why you want to preserve a list with one item in it?

Comment: I didn't want to preserve the list. I wanted to show that the list(1) was lists(1). only the object. Sorry for the typo, but your answer helped me a lot Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `map` with `flatmap`  and create a collection of pairs:

```
.flatMap{l => 
    val pk = l.get[String]("pk")
    l.getList[String]("lists").map(item => (pk,List(item)))
}
```