# Convert Map<String, NavigableMap<Long, Collection<String>>> to List<String> using Java8

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to convert `Map<String, NavigableMap<Long, Collection<String>>>` into  `List<String>` Java 8.

I wrote some code but got stuck some where in mid.

```
userTopics.values().stream().map(
    new Function<NavigableMap<Long, Collection<String>>, Collection<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Collection<String> apply(NavigableMap<Long, Collection<String>> t) {
            return null;  //TODO
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just [`flatMap` that s**t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559537/where-does-the-flatmap-that-s-idiomatic-expression-in-scala-come-from):

```
List<String> values = nestedMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(toList());
```

As [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682522/conert-mapstring-navigablemaplong-collectionstring-to-liststring-using/35682553?noredirect=1#comment59042769_35682553) points out, this is neater:

```
List<String> values = nestedMap.values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: A funny anti-pattern, even twice. `entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue)` instead of streaming over the desired items in the first place: `values().stream()`

Comment: @cody123: it's the same as `.map(entry -> entry.getValue())` with `entry` being of type `Map.Entry`. When you also need the keys in an intermediate stream operation, streaming over the entries via `entrySet().stream()` and mapping to the values once a stream of values is needed, is the right solution. However, when you need the values *only*, you can right stream over the values in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Two `flatMaps` will do, flat the `NavigableMap` and then flat the `Collection` inside.

```
List<String> result = mapOfMaps.values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(v -> v.values().stream())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```