# How to transform a item in RDD(Spark) to many items in RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I get a RDD with 'Scan' action from 'HBase'.
Each item in this RDD is like: x1, y1, y2, y3...
So the items in this RDD are like(each line is a row result of scan action):

1. x1, y1, y2, y3
2. x2, y1, y4, y8, y9
3. x3, y5
4. ......
5. xn, y1, y6, y100

I want transform this RDD to another RDD like:

1. x1, y1
2. x1, y2
3. x1, y3
4. x2, y1
5. x2, y4
6. ...
7. xn, y1
8. xn, y6
9. xn, y100

How can I do this transform?

Comment: I assume the 2nd item is a typo...and should be x1 instead of x2

Comment: yes, it is a typo. I modify it. Thanks ! @JustinPihony

Answer (score 2):

["flatMap that sh*t"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559537/where-does-the-flatmap-that-s-idiomatic-expression-in-scala-come-from):

```
rdd.flatMap(x => {
  val key = x.head
  x.tail.map(y=>(key,y))
})
```

Comment: No, it's not simply combine the head with each item in the tail. If you observe the last few examples, the 2nd item is computed by `f(xn)`.

Comment: @davidshen84 What makes you think that?

Comment: Sorry, the 2nd item is a typo. I have edited it.@davidshen84