# Extracting first defined value(if any) from sequence of suppliers of optional values

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, vavr

Given a sequence of `Supplier<Option<T>>` -- e.g., a list of method references -- what's the idiomatic way to get the first defined result, if any? Ideally without invoking any more suppliers after the first successful result.

What I have now is:

```
Stream<Supplier<Option<Foo>>> suppliers = Stream.of(
  bar::fooOption,
  baz::fooOption,
  qux::fooOption
);

Option<Foo> firstDefined = suppliers.map(Supplier::get)
  .find(Option::isDefined)
  .flatMap(Function.identity());
```

but it seems like there ought to be a way to [flatmap that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559537/where-does-the-flatmap-that-s-idiomatic-expression-in-scala-come-from)  even flatter.

Comment: Your solution seems perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Not sure why `scala` is tagged, but it would be something like `suppliers.collectFirst{_.get}` in Scala.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I tagged it Scala because the Vavr library is Scala-inspired and “here’s how you would do it in Scala” is often the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only see an alternative solution with equal number of steps as yours.

```
Option<Foo> firstDefined = suppliers.map(Supplier::get)
        .find(Option::isDefined)
        .map(Option::get);
```

If you can do with a simple `map` instead of a `flatMap`, use that instead, as it will be usually faster, especially on multi-valued monadic containers. There's probably not much difference though for 0/1 valued monads, like `Option`, perhaps on the contrary, it might be a tad slower in this case, as it creates an additional `Option`.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `flatMap` :)

```
 suppliers.flatMap(_.get).headOption
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest. I'm curious about performance in light of [Nándor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45290259/27358), but not curious enough to actually benchmark it. :)

Comment: @DavidMoles  don't think performance difference between map and flatmap is worth considering. `Option.get` is generally considered "code smell" in FP on the other hand. So, my advice would be the opposite: always prefer `flatMap` (or `flatten`) to "unwrapping" options explicitly.