# Use Vavr pattern matching to convert Option to Try, failing for unrecognized values

Tags: java, pattern-matching, vavr

Say I have two interfaces, `A` and `B`. `A` has three known implementations, `A1`, `A2`, and `A3`; `B` has three corresponding concrete wrapper classes, `B1`, `B2`, and `B3`, such that the constructor of `B1` takes an `A1`, `B2` takes an `A2`, and so on.

I have a method that returns an `Option<A>`, and I want to convert it to a `Try<Option<B>>`, where if the `A` is one of the known implementations (or `None`) it gets wrapped with the corresponding `B` implementation as a `Success<B>`, and otherwise it's a `Failure`. What I currently have is something like:

```
Option<A> myA = getA();
Try<Option<B>> wrapped = Match(myA).of(
  Case($Some($(instanceof(A1.class))), a -> Success(Some(B1(a)))),
  Case($Some($(instanceof(A2.class))), a -> Success(Some(B2(a)))),
  Case($Some($(instanceof(A3.class))), a -> Success(Some(B3(a)))),
  Case($None(), a -> Success(None())),
  Case($(), Failure(new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown A type: " + myA)))
);
```

This seems unnecessarily horrible. Is there some way I can [flatmap this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559537/where-does-the-flatmap-that-s-idiomatic-expression-in-scala-come-from)  ?

Comment: Hi David, isn't it Option<A> and Try<Option<B>> instead of A and Try<B>?

Comment: Hi @DanielDietrich—sorry, there were a lot of typos in there. Yes, it should have been Option<A> and Try<Option<B>>.

Comment: FWIW, the eventual target is an [io.reactivex.Maybe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html), which (as I understand it so far) is sort of an asynchronous Try/Option combination: it can provide one value, no values, or an error.

Comment: I think the code smell is that the implementation of B depends on the implementation of A. Why would that be?

Comment: @durron597 This code is converting between two different APIs with parallel data structures. There are a number of possible approaches other than this one, but the general question of "how do I convert an unmatched case to a Try failure" is relevant in other circumstances.

Comment: @DavidMoles is that the part that you thought was stinky? The part I found stinky was the matching in the first place. If you assume that the first three cases of your `Match` are basically correct, then I think it follows that `$(), Failure(...` is also correct.