# Java 8 alternative for validating data inside multiple nested loops

Tags: java, java-8

I have a question regarding validating data in a nested for loop.

```
public class Object1{
  private String obj1Name;

  private String obj1Desc;

  private List<Object2> object2List;

  //Setters and getters
}


public class Object2{
  private String obj2Name;

  private String obj2Desc;

  private List<Object3> object3List;

  //Setters and getters
}

public class Object3{
  private String obj3Name;

  private String obj3Desc;
  //Setters and getters
}
```

I wish to validate both `name` and `desc` in all objects, instead of using a nested loop like the following:

```
List<Object1> object1List = getObject1List();

for(Object1 object1 : object1List ){
   if(object1.getObj1Name() == null){
     //throw error
   }

   if(object1.getObj1Desc() == null){
     //throw error
   }

   for(Object2 object2 : object1.getObject2List()){
        if(object2.getObj2Name() == null){
            //throw error
        }

        if(object2.getObj2Desc() == null){
            //throw error
        }

        //loop Object 3 ...
   }
}
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: are you throwing the same error on each condition ? if so, what type of error?

Comment: yes, throwing same error on each condition, the error will be `InvalidParameterException`

Comment: You might find useful https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html

Comment: don't get me wrong but have you considered a framework with support for `@NotNull`?

Comment: @Eugene Exactly what I wanted to point out as well. I mean that's what something like `javax.validation.constraints` are meant for.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza yeah, know about this, but still need to iterate through the loop right?

Comment: @hades yes, you can't avoid that, but you can take a look at posted answers to use streams

Answer (score 4):

I am just going to say it here, so that no one does what you want to do - use a proper framework for this, personally I would go for [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) - super easy to integrate and use IMO. It will support that nesting that you have without any problems and there are tons of tutorials online (even their own is good) and how to achieve that; hint: a few dependencies and a few annotations and you are done.

Comment: yeah, i actually know about hibernate validator, normally i use it to validate object request in `@RequestBody`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, it don't come into my mind because i thought there is no way triggering the validation process, but it actually has.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** An idea to externalize the check, you need to create Functional Interface

```
ObjectValidatorInterface ov = new ObjectValidator();
if(!object1List.stream().allMatch(o -> ov.validate(o, Object1.class))) {
        // throw error;
}
```

And the interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ObjectValidatorInterface {
    boolean validate(Object object, Class clazz);
}

class ObjectValidator implements ObjectValidatorInterface {

    public boolean validate(Object object, Class clazz) {
        boolean valid = false;

        if(Object1.class.getName().equals(clazz.getName())) {
            valid = validateObject1((Object1) object);

        } else if(Object2.class.getName().equals(clazz.getName())) {
            valid = validateObject2((Object2) object);

        } else if(Object3.class.getName().equals(clazz.getName())) {
            valid = validateObject3((Object3) object);
        }

        return valid;
    }

    private boolean validateObject1(Object1 o) {
        boolean valid;
        valid = o.getObj1Name() != null && o.getObj1Desc() != null;
        if(!(o.getObject2List() == null || o.getObject2List().isEmpty())) {
            valid = valid && o.getObject2List().stream().allMatch(o2 -> validate(o2, Object2.class));
        }
        return valid;
    }

    private boolean validateObject2(Object2 o) {
        boolean valid;
        valid = o.getObj2Name() != null && o.getObj2Desc() != null;
        if(!(o.getObject3List() == null || o.getObject3List().isEmpty())) {
            valid = valid && o.getObject3List().stream().allMatch(o3 -> validate(o3, Object3.class));
        }
        return valid;
    }

    private boolean validateObject3(Object3 o) {
        return o.getObj3Name() != null && o.getObj3Desc() != null;
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You might be able to do it by delegating the validation to each object:

```
List<Object1> object1List = getObject1List();

if(!object1List.stream().allMatch(Object1::isValid)) {
    //throw error
}
```

And add an `isValid` method to each object

```
public class Object1 {
    private String obj1Name;
    private String obj1Desc;
    private List<Object2> object2List;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return obj1Name != null
            && obj1Desc != null
            && object2List.stream().allMatch(Object2::isValid);
    }
}

public class Object2 {
    private String obj2Name;
    private String obj2Desc;
    private List<Object3> object3List;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return obj2Name != null
            && obj2Desc != null
            && object3List.stream().allMatch(Object3::isValid);
    }
}

public class Object3 {
    private String obj3Name;
    private String obj3Desc;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return obj3Name != null
            && obj3Desc != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really dislike this - you put the validation conditions inside the POJO itself - is this ever a good idea? what if there are 100 of these?

Comment: good one, but I think these `isValid` methods should be moved out of the POJO classes

Comment: @Bentaye nope, the field names are different - this would not work

Comment: @Eugene Added an other version where the check is done by an external object

Comment: @Bentaye well that is a bit better, I agree. But now, imagine supporting that and testing it correctly, with at least 10 different validation types and rules... you might be on the verge of the next mission impossible movie, which I would not want to be part of

Comment: @Eugene yes sure, but the OP does not specify how many classes he needs to validate, so assuming 3 as in his example

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can definitely avoid the "nesting" by using the Stream API:

```
if(object1List.stream()
                .anyMatch(a -> a.getObj1Name() == null ||
                        a.getObj1Desc() == null)){
    // throw error
}else if(object1List.stream()
                .anyMatch(a -> a.getObject2List().stream()
                       .anyMatch(b -> b.getObj2Name() == null ||
                                            b.getObj2Desc() == null))){
    // throw error
}else if(object1List.stream()
                .anyMatch(a -> a.getObject2List().stream()
                        .anyMatch(b -> b.getObject3List().stream()
                                .anyMatch(c -> c.getObj3Name() == null ||
                                                      c.getObj3Desc() == null)))){
     // throw error
}
```

Another approach being more compact, but probably less efficient:

```
boolean result = object1List.stream()
                .flatMap(a -> a.getObject2List().stream()
                        .flatMap(b -> b.getObject3List().stream()
                                .flatMap(c -> Stream.of(a.getObj1Name(),
                                        a.getObj1Desc(), b.getObj2Name(),
                                        b.getObj2Desc(), c.getObj3Name(), c.getObj3Desc()))))
                .anyMatch(Objects::isNull); 

if(result){ // throw error }
```

So, to conclude if performance is a concern then proceed with your approach or try and see if the parallel stream API can do you any good, otherwise, the above should suffice.

Comment: to me, it's way worse than OP's approach

Comment: @AndrewTobilko the goal was to remove the nesting, and even in terms of efficiency that really depends on the number of elements in the source.

Comment: Yeah, [flatmap that shit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559537/where-does-the-flatmap-that-s-idiomatic-expression-in-scala-come-from).

Answer (score 1):

A **validator**, as a functional interface, is a `Consumer` which consumes a value of a specific type, performs checks and throws an Exception if something is off.

Traversal of the data structure (Tree) can be accomplished over **streams** (`peek` to **visit** a node, `flatmap` to **recurse** into the children). For the validation, we introduce a **NO-OP map operation**, which validates and returns the value, allowing the stream to continue.

```
BiConsumer<String, Object> checkRequired = (name, value) -> {
    if (value == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " is required");
    }
};

Consumer<Object1> obj1Validator = obj1 -> {
    checkRequired.accept("Object1", obj1);
    checkRequired.accept("obj1Name", obj1.getObj1Name());
    checkRequired.accept("obj1Desc", obj1.getObj1Desc());
};

Consumer<Object2> obj2Validator = obj2 -> {
    checkRequired.accept("Object2", obj2);
    checkRequired.accept("obj2Name", obj2.getObj2Name());
    checkRequired.accept("obj2Desc", obj2.getObj2Desc());
};

Consumer<Object3> obj3Validator = obj3 -> {
    checkRequired.accept("Object3", obj3);
    checkRequired.accept("obj3Name", obj3.getObj3Name());
    checkRequired.accept("obj3Desc", obj3.getObj3Desc());
};

Object1 obj1 = ...; // assign some value

Stream.of(obj1)
    .peek(obj1Validator)
    .filter(x -> x.getObject2List() != null)
    .map(Object1::getObject2List)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .peek(obj2Validator)
    .map(Object2::getObject3List)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .peek(obj3Validator)
    .count();
```

Comment: now imagine supporting this for numerous rules and fields... seriously, don't.

Comment: @Eugene that's what validation is about - check each model and each field. Of course that validation can be delegated to a framework, such as using Bean Validation (JSR-380) which drives field validations over annotations.

Comment: would you write this code or use a framework? that was my point

Comment: I would certainly use a framework, in particular Bean Validation (JSR-380, https://beanvalidation.org/specification)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a function/loop which sifts through an object(The generic Object). That way, you won't have to run a separate for loop for each object if the name of the member variable "desc"  is uniform in all the three objects. But that's another level of nesting so not sure you'd want to use that if you're just looking to avoid nesting.

Answer (score 0):

If their validation seems to be the same, only the type change, then use interface have `Object1`, `Object2` and `Object3` implements `ICommon`:

```
interface ICommon {
  String getField1();
  int getField2();
  Iterable<? extends ICommon> getChildren();
}
```

Then have this:

```
private void validate0(String prefix, ICommon common) {
  if (common.getField1() == null) throw new ValidationException(prefix + ".field1 can't be null");
  if (common.getField2() == null) throw new ValidationException(prefix + ".field2 can't be null");
  int index = 0;
  for (ICommon child : getChildren()) {
     validate0(prefix + ".children[" + index + "]", child);
    ++index;
  }
}

public void validate(ICommon common) {
   validate0("common", common);
}
```

You may also invert this using a `BiConsumer<String, ICommon>` (or `Consumer<ICommon>`)  to validate if you don't care about proper error reporting).

- This will also make it clearer about which validation may apply on your object
- Using stream does not (always) make it clearer (see [Peter Walser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53633476/1023553) answer and try to understand the big stream :)).

Answer (score 0):

Make use of ConstraintViolation and javax annotations
[validation using javax](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_validating_constraints)

```
public class Object1{
@NotNull
private String obj1Name;
@NotNull
private String obj1Desc;
@NotNull
private List<Object2> object2List;
}


public class Object2{
@NotNull
private String obj2Name;
@NotNull
private String obj2Desc;

}

public Object1 validate() throws someValidationException {
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

Object1 object1 = new Object1();
    provision = new ObjectMapper().readValue(rawJson, Object1.class);

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object1>> constraintViolations =
            validator.validate( object1 );
    if(constraintViolations.size()>1) {
 //throw some exception when object 2 is null for example and some constraint is 
//violated 
}
     return object1;
}
```