# Using streams instead of nested for loops

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, nested-loops

I'm currently learning java 8 streams. I have a list of integers, with values from 1 to 1000. Now, I want to create a new list of integers, where each element is the result of multiplying each element of the *numbers* list with each other element of the *numbers* list.

The following code does the job:

```
        List<Integer> numbers = IntStream
                .range(1,999)
                .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Integer> products = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer i : numbers) {
            for (Integer j : numbers) {
                products.add(i*j);
            }
        }
```

I would like to know if there's a way to avoid the nested for loop by using streams?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
List<Integer> products = numbers.stream()
        .flatMap(i -> numbers.stream().map(j -> i * j))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`i -> numbers.stream().map(j -> i * j)` is a `Function` to get a `Stream` of products for a particular `i`. Use it to generate a `Stream<Integer>` for each element in `numbers`, [`flatMap` that s***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559537/where-does-the-flatmap-that-s-idiomatic-expression-in-scala-come-from), and collect the result into a `List`.

I wouldn't say it looks/performs better than the plain version you've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

*in terms of speed and readability, I strongly recommend the previously mentioned solution from Avi*

```
List<Integer> products = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.forEach( i -> numbers.forEach( j -> products.add( i * j ) ) );
```